# Finding $G(0)$ given the steady-state error in a closed negative feedback loop

Tags: control-theory

I'm  having some trouble with the following question:

> Consider a system with transfer function $G(s)$, placed in a negative unity feedback loop. Knowing that the closed-loop system is stable and has a steady-state error of $1$ when we input a step of amplitude 2 (this is $u(t)=2,t\geq0$ and $u(t)=0,t<0$), what is the value of $G(0)$?

I draw the following block diagram for the system:

[image]

I got the following expression for $E(s)$: $$E(s)=\frac{1}{1+H(s)}U(s)$$

We know that $e_{ss}=\lim_{t\to\infty}e(t)=\lim_{s\to 0}sE(s) = 1$. Assuming the continuity of $H$, we get: $$\frac{2}{1+H(0)}=1 \implies H(0)=1$$

Now, We get the following expression for the transfer function $G$: $$Y(s)=H(s)E(s)=\underbrace{\frac{H(s)}{1+H(s)}}_{G(s)}U(s)$$

So, assuming the continuity of $G$:
$$G(0)=\frac{H(0)}{1+H(0)} = 1/2$$

---

The problem is, according to my teacher, the correct answer is $G(0)=1$.
I don't see what I did wrong. Where is the mistake?

Comment: You are asked to find $G(s)$ which is $H(s)$ on your diagram. Your $G(s)$ is the closed-loop transfer function. So, you are done with the first part of your calculations.

Comment: But why am I getting the wrong result then? @KBS

Comment: You are getting the correct result. Read again what I said.

Comment: Thank you. I just asked again, because this question appeared on my exam, and the teacher said that G(0) is 1, not 1/2 @KBS

Comment: Do you understand where your confusion is?